# Change images on hover with AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Okay, so I need to change images on hover in my Angular app. However, due to some peculiarities of the site, it wasn't really feasible to change images on hover via css [without a ton of extra work], which would have been the best way, I realize.

So instead, I'm using ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave to change the images on hover.

**landing.jade**

```
img.share-button(src='images/btn_share.png', ng-click='dropdownShareIcons()')
                img.share-icon-top(src='{{ shareIcons[0].orig }}', data-id='0', ng-mouseenter='colorizeIcons($event)', ng-mouseleave='decolorizeIcons($event)')
                img.share-icon-top(src='{{ shareIcons[1].orig }}', data-id='1', ng-mouseenter='colorizeIcons($event)', ng-mouseleave='decolorizeIcons($event)')
                img.share-icon-top(src='{{ shareIcons[2].orig }}', data-id='2', ng-mouseenter='colorizeIcons($event)', ng-mouseleave='decolorizeIcons($event)')
```

Then in the controller I have an object which contains the paths to the images, and the functions which switch images on hover.

**landing.js**

```
$scope.shareIcons = [
        {orig: 'images/follow_weibo_grey.png', hover: 'images/follow_weibo_colored.png'},
        {orig: 'images/follow_wechat_grey.png', hover: 'images/follow_wechat_colored.png'},
        {orig: 'images/follow_youku_grey.png', hover: 'images/follow_youku_colored.png'},
        ]


    $scope.colorizeIcons = function($event) {
        $event.target.src = $scope.shareIcons[$event.target.dataset.id].hover;
    }

    $scope.decolorizeIcons = function($event) {
        $event.target.src = $scope.shareIcons[$event.target.dataset.id].orig;
    }
```

This all works fine and well on my local environment, but on the production server it is veeeerrrrry slow. Like, 2-3 seconds to switch the images.

So my question is - is there an easy way to fix this? Either something within angular or a workaround/hack. Doesnt really matter as long as image switch time is sped up a bit. Or is it going to continue to be slow as long as I'm switching images via JS like this? Ideally, I would like avoid rewriting this using CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey bro I had the same problem, and all I could think of doing was preloading the images. That helped alot. Add a small piece of js code which loads asynchronously at the beginning of your document. Like this for example:

```
var images = new Array()
  function preload() {
    for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
      images[i] = new Image()
      images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
    }
  }
  preload(
    // for (i = 0; i < $scope.members.length; i ++){
    //   return members[i].source + ",";
    // }
    "http://ramiawar.co/pages/speakersPage/pages/team/assets/images/image1.1.jpg",
    "http://ramiawar.co/pages/speakersPage/pages/team/assets/images/image2.1.jpg",
    "http://ramiawar.co/pages/speakersPage/pages/team/assets/images/image3.1.jpg",
    "http://ramiawar.co/pages/speakersPage/pages/team/assets/images/image4.1.jpg",
    "http://ramiawar.co/pages/speakersPage/pages/team/assets/images/image5.1.jpg",
    "http://ramiawar.co/pages/speakersPage/pages/team/assets/images/image6.1.jpg"
  )
```

Comment: Thanks you. I had figured this out, but by the time I did so, I had long forgotten about this question. Glad you answered it for anyone else who might run into the same problem in the future. : )

Answer (score 0):

I would consider optimizing the PNG image sizes. There are batch optimization tools available online, here is a blog post comparing a few of them to get you started: http://www.sitepoint.com/image-compression-tools/ 
perhaps you can test optimize a couple of images to see if you notice a change?

GL!